# How to save an image from SQL Server to MS Access .mdb

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ms-access, arrays

I have a SQL Server database with a table that has a column that stores an image. I have another database and I would like to store the image from the SQL Server database into it. It's type is MS Access 2000 format .mdb.

The problem is I get back the content of the column and I put them in an array of bytes as follows:

```
 Dim arrByte() As Byte = CType(dtAll.Rows(0)("DailyProgram_Image"), Byte())
```

It sends me back the data of the image as byte type. When I try to save this into the access DB it give me an error because of type mismatch.

Comment: Is your access table field set to the type of 'Ole Object'?

Comment: Please can you provide details of the access table, and also the code you're trying to use to save the byte array into the access Table.

Comment: There are some notes here that may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398437/store-byte-in-access-2010/3398696#3398696

Comment: Do you know that it's when you save you get the error? The source line you've included in your answer appear to be the one where you fetch the image.

Comment: Okay now the type of the cloumn is OLE object.
I try to insert it as a normal insert statemnt "INSERT INTO [Desc_Image] Values (@Desc_Image)"
And i get back the image from the SQL and but it in the arrByte then I try to insert it on the Access File

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeproject has an article about uploading and downloading BLOBs to Access here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/AccessBlob.aspx

Comment: thanks but this work only for the other type of access not the .mdb one

Comment: Are you sure? The screen dump has a file with .mdb.