# ADO recordset to DAO recordset (VB.net) 

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, dao

In my webservice I have converted the ado recordset to xml and returned a string.
In my application I managed to convert it back to the ado recordset but now I need to convert that recordset to dao as I need to use some of the functions provided by dao that ado does not have.

Answer (score 0):

What functions would these be?  What are you trying to do?

I don't think you will have much luck converting an ADO recordset to DAO as they are two competing data access APIs.  About the only way I can think you do it is if you added a COM reference to your project to DAO 3.6 and manually built the DAO recordset on the fly using the structure and data of the ADO recordset.

Comment: I need to access the attachment field from MS access and only DAO is able to do that. How do you manually build the dao recordset?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779211/programmatically-managing-microsoft-access-attachment-typed-field-with-net

Comment: Actually, I believe this thread has a working solution for you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/296b0303-a50b-4231-95e6-ebb44a70fef8